# Login into a website Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

I do not know a lot for HTML and I'm trying to log in this website through vba:
www.gambolao.net

That is the code I am using:

```
Sub Login()
    Dim IEexp As InternetExplorer
    Set IEexp = New InternetExplorer
    IEexp.Visible = True
    IEexp.navigate "http://www.gambolao.net"

    Do While IEexp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Dim userName As HTMLInputElement
    Set userName = IEexp.document.getElementByName("username")

    Dim userPW As HTMLInputElement
    Set userPW = IEexp.document.getElementById("password")

    userName.innerText = "myUsername"
    userPW.innerText = "myPassword"

    IEexp.document.getElementById("submit").Click

    IEexp.Quit
    Set IEexp = Nothing
End Sub
```

However, It looks like I am missing something.
Can anybody guide me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to use WebRequest instead and post your username and password to the login page and based on the html result, you determine whether the login is successful or not?

Comment: Hi @Hatjhie, Didn't get your point..

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Let's try this. As I didn't test the code, let me know if it's working. Please see the highlighted post:

```
Sub Login()
    Dim IEexp As InternetExplorer
    Set IEexp = New InternetExplorer
    IEexp.Visible = True
    IEexp.navigate "http://www.gambolao.net"

    Do While IEexp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Dim userName As HTMLInputElement
    Set userName = IEexp.document.getElementByName("username")

    Dim userPW As HTMLInputElement
    Set userPW = **IEexp.document.getElementByName("pw")**

    userName.innerText = "myUsername"
    userPW.innerText = "myPassword"

    **IEexp.document.getElementByName("pw")[0].nextSibling.click()**

    IEexp.Quit
    Set IEexp = Nothing
End Sub
```